# Can't get SVG image to work in IOS lockscreen widget

Tags: swift, svg, swiftui, widgetkit, lockscreenwidget

please consider the following widget view (the entry.icon is a string which points to a resource where the file is an SVG):

```
case .accessoryCircular:
VStack{
    Image(entry.icon).resizable().padding().border(.red)
    Text("IN")
}
```

The image works if it's a PNG but now it's an SVG. I'm pretty much a SwiftUI noob, so I don't know how to get the image to work within the circular widget... or perhaps SVG isn't supported in lock screen widgets?
The error message I'm getting from the preview is

> The body of the Widget's entries contains an image of size(2094, 2010) which is beyond the maximum of (1418,8, 3067,2).

Do I have to set the size explicitly?? In that case, I have to hard-code it to some fixed widget size, right? I'd like to avoid that if possible.
Grateful for the pointers.

Comment: the entry.icon points to a resource where the file is an svg.

Comment: Ah, you mean in the file itself :) <svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="698.000000pt" height="670.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 698.000000 670.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">